# How do i find the minimum of two dataframe columns with multi-indices in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have got two pandas Dataframes `df1` and `df2`. `df1` has a multi-index:

```
                  A   
instance index
a        0        10 
         1        11  
         2        7
b        0        8
         1        9
         2        13
```

The frame `df2` has the same first-level index as `df1`:

```
              B   
instance 
a             5 
b             12
```

I want to do two things:

1) Assign the values in `df2` to the all the rows of `df1`

```
                  A    B
instance index
a        0        10   5
         1        11   5
         2        7    5
b        0        8    12
         1        9    12
         2        13   12
```

2) Create a dataframe object that represents the minimum of values in `A` and `B` without concatenating the two dataframes like above:

```
min(df1,df2):
                  min   
instance index
a        0        5   
         1        5   
         2        5   
b        0        8    
         1        9    
         2        12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first request, you can use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
>>> df1.join(df2)
                 A   B
instance index        
a        0      10   5
         1      11   5
         2       7   5
b        0       8  12
         1       9  12
         2      13  12
```

For your second, you can simply call `min(axis=1)` on that object:

```
>>> df1.join(df2).min(axis=1).to_frame("min")
                min
instance index     
a        0        5
         1        5
         2        5
b        0        8
         1        9
         2       12
```